Screen flashes when I type a value in or edit a RadioButton
this is my code:
It flashes white when I edit the textinputs or click on the radio buttons i think it's because its rerendering it and I don't know how to fix that and I've tried to use React.memo, but I don't think it helped.
export default function CompanyHomePage() {
  
    const PostJobModal = () => {
        return (
            <Modal>
                    <ProgressSteps>
                        <ProgressStep label="Description" nextBtnTextStyle={styles.progressStepText1} previousBtnTextStyle={styles.progressStepText}>
                            <DescriptionStep/>
                        </ProgressStep>
                        <ProgressStep label="Job Type" nextBtnTextStyle={styles.progressStepText1} previousBtnTextStyle={styles.progressStepText}>
                            <JobTypeStep/>
                        </ProgressStep>
                    </ProgressSteps>
            </Modal>
        )
    }

    const DescriptionStep = React.memo(() => {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.questionText}>Job Title</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInputSmall}
                    onChangeText={text => setJobTitle(text)}
                />
                <Text style={styles.questionText}>Location</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInputSmall}
                    value={location}
                    onChangeText={text => setLocation(text)}
                />
                <View>
                    <Text style={{color: "#1348AA", fontSize: 14, fontFamily: "LibreBaskerville-Bold", fontWeight: "400", width: "100%", textAlign: "left", left: 90, marginTop: -20,}}>Current Location</Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.questionText}>Description</Text>
                <TextInput
                    multiline={true}
                    style={styles.textInputBig}
                    onChangeText={text => setDescription(text)}
                />
            </View>
        )
    });
    const JobTypeStep = React.memo(() => {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.questionText}>Job Type</Text>
                <RadioGroup
                    radioButtons={radioButtons}
                    onPress={setSelectedId}
                    selectedId={selectedId}
                    layout='row'
                />
            </View>
        )
    });
}

Hey, this is my code:
It flashes white when I edit the textinputs or click on the radio buttons i think it's because its rerendering it and I don't know how to fix that and I've tried to use React.memo, but I don't think it helped.Hey, this is my code:
It flashes white when I edit the textinputs or click on the radio buttons i think it's because its rerendering it and I don't know how to fix that and I've tried to use React.memo, but I don't think it helped.

You should avoid creating components within components. At every re-render, every non-hook statement gets re-executed. So when you create a component within a component, it will be re-created at every re-render. I think that is why your screen flashes white whenever text is typed or the radio button is pressed.
You tried to fix the problem with memo, but its not a hook; so your components are still recreated at every re-render. You could try using useCallback or useMemo to get better results; but I think it would be much better to just move components to their own file and pass them the props they need

This video may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sAdzy90GtE
